# DATABASE: Mysql.com was hacked twice this year should we still use mysql for our database?

Tags: mysql

Last March(2011)
http://techie-buzz.com/tech-news/mysql-com-database-compromised-sql-injection.html

This Month(2011)
http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/240609/mysqlcom_hacked_to_serve_malware.html

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the database wasn't hacked. The database did exactly what it was supposed to.

The application in front of the database was hacked.

Use any database and put a foul lot of code directly touching tables and you'll end up with a hackable pile.